# Codeigniter set_value() and populate the form value

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, retain

My form field looks like this

```
    echo form_label('Quantity', 'quantity');
    echo form_input('quantity', $quantityx);
```

I modified it to retain form values

```
    echo form_label('Quantity', 'quantity');
    echo form_input('quantity', $this->input->post('quantity'));
```

I set the $quantityx above in the code behind in order to populate a value from the database so a user can edit a row.

How can I retain the value for validations, and have a variable to populate from the database at the same time?

I have tried this a well

```
    echo form_label('Quantity', 'quantity');
    echo form_input('quantity', set_value($quantityx));
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set them like this, if `set_value('columnanme')` returns `false` then a form `$_POST` did not take place so what it will do is get the data from the data base example
`$profile->firstname`

```
$firstname = set_value('firstname') == false ? $profile->firstname : set_value('firstname');
$lastname = set_value('lastname') == false ? $profile->lastname : set_value('lastname');
```

Use it like:

```
echo form_label('Firstname', 'fname');
echo form_input('firstname', $firstname);
echo form_label('Firstname', 'lnamey');
echo form_input('firstname', $lastname);
```

in your case you can do:

```
$quantity = set_value('Quantity') == false ? $quantityx : set_value('Quantity');
```

ANd on your form:

```
echo form_label('Quantity', 'quantity');
    echo form_input('quantity', $quantity);
```

***Assuming that `$quantityx` holds the data from your databse***

**EDIT**
**=============================================**

Just use `set_values()` second parameter as the default value. i.e `set_value('name_of_input_field',$data_from_databse_as_default);`
If this does not work, then use my first answer.

Comment: Instead I would prefer just using the second parameter within set_value instead off doing unnecessary if else checks. eg.
`echo form_input('quantity', set_value('quantity', $profile->firstname) )`. The 2nd parameter is the fallback value.

Answer (score 2):

To populate the value below code worked for me.

```
form_input('cat_name','{YOUR VALUE}',array('id' => 'cat_name', ''placeHolder'' => 'Enter Cat Name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to set the value in the text field while validating and fetch the value from the database.

```
form_input(array('id' => 'cat_name', 'name' => 'cat_name','value'=>set_value('cat_name',$cat_name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 basic types of inputs. Here's how to repopulate each of them.

## Text Inputs

```
$quantity = getValueFromDb();
echo form_input(
    ['name' => 'textInput',],
    set_value('textInput', $quantity, false)
);
```

Use `false` as third parameter of `set_value` to avoid double html escaping, which is done by `form_input` as well.

## Dropdowns

```
$quantity = getValueFromDb();
$quantities = getQuantitiesList();
echo form_dropdown(
    [ 'name' => 'formDropdown'],
    [''=>'-- Select Quantity --'] + $quantities,
    set_value('formDropdown', $quantity, false)
);
```

## Radio Buttons

```
$quantity = getValueFromDb();
echo form_radio(
    ['name'=>'formRadio'],
    5,
    set_radio('formRadio', 5, $quantity === 5)
), 5;
echo form_radio(
    ['name'=>'formRadio'],
    10,
    set_radio('formRadio', 10, $quantity === 10)
), 10;
```

For radio inputs, use loops for substituting literals.

## Checkboxes

Checkboxes can be made in a similar fashion by replacing `form_radio` with `form_checkbox` and `set_radio` with `set_checkbox`.

```
$values = [ 5 => 'Five', 10 => 'Ten', 15 => 'Fifteen',];
$selectedValues = [5, 15];
foreach ($values as $value => $label) {
    echo form_checkbox(
        ['name' => 'formCheckbox[]'],
        $value,
        set_checkbox(
            'formCheckbox[]', 
            $value,
            in_array($value, $selectedValues, true)
        )
    ), $label;
}
```